# How to execute a single databricks notebook in a data factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory pipeline with multiple databricks notebooks. The debug option is executing the whole pipeline and I couldn't find any option to execute a single notebook. Is there any way we can execute only a single notebook instead of the whole pipeline?

Comment: Hi @praneethh, If the answer is helpful for you, hope can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we can't.  it's not supported for now.

We can't execute only a single notebook instead of the whole pipeline.

But if the single notebook is failed,  we can only run the failed actives in pipeline without the whole pipeline:

- From the pipeline run view inside ADF monitoring pane, you can see
  the list of activities, their run status, and from there you can
  choose the option to rerun from a certain activity in the middle of
  the pipeline, rather from the beginning of the pipeline.

Ref here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/34270504-run-individual-failed-activities-only-instead-comp